# JSFiddle Example Works, But Not on GitHub Pages

Tags: javascript, webrtc

This code works on JSFiddle.net:

html:

```
<script src="https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/dist/RTCMultiConnection.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

css:

```
video {
  width: 40%;
  border-radius:15px;
  margin: 5px 10px;
}
```

js:

```
var connection = new RTCMultiConnection();

// this line is VERY_important
connection.socketURL = 'https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com:443/';

// all below lines are optional; however recommended.

connection.session = {
    audio: true,
    video: true
};

connection.sdpConstraints.mandatory = {
    OfferToReceiveAudio: true,
    OfferToReceiveVideo: true
};

connection.onstream = function(event) {
    document.body.appendChild( event.mediaElement );
};

var predefinedRoomId = prompt('Please enter room-id', 'xyzxyzxyz');

connection.openOrJoin(predefinedRoomId);
```

but when I combine and put it all on GitHub Pages hosting with the addition of a notification js snippet, the js doesn't see to activate at all and it just shows the basic page.

HTML/CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<title>
 Instant Call
</title>
<style>
video {
  width: 40%;
  border-radius:15px;
  margin: 5px 10px;
}
</style>
<body>
  <p>Instant Conference</p>
  <script src="https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/dist/RTCMultiConnection.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src ="notifi.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

notifi.JS:

```
if (window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission() == 0) {
  window.webkitNotifications.createNotification('icon.png', 'Notification Title', 'Notification content...');
} else {
  // Note that we can't call requestPermission from here as we are in the
  // callback function and not triggered just on user action
  console.log('You have to click on "Set notification permissions for this page" ' + 'first to be able to receive notifications.');
  return;
}



var connection = new RTCMultiConnection();

// this line is VERY_important
connection.socketURL = 'https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com:443/';

// all below lines are optional; however recommended.

connection.session = {
    audio: true,
    video: true
};

connection.sdpConstraints.mandatory = {
    OfferToReceiveAudio: true,
    OfferToReceiveVideo: true
};

connection.onstream = function(event) {
    document.body.appendChild( event.mediaElement );
};

var predefinedRoomId = prompt('Please enter room-id', 'xyzxyzxyz');

connection.openOrJoin(predefinedRoomId);
```

||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||\
 EDIT 8/17-5:17PM ET

It now successfully shows only on one end of the connection (one user/device)****

It ought to notify all users when a user joins the chatroom, and show both of their live webcam feeds at the same time. In the JSfiddle this works, but not on github pages.

||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
EDIT 8/17/18 8:47 PM EST

Got everything working expect for this line which ought to notify participants of newly joined users:

```
if (connection.newParticipant === true) {
  var notification = new Notification("New Call!");
}
```

Here's the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
video {
  width: 40%;
  border-radius:15px;
  margin: 5px 10px;
}
</style>
<body>

<h1>Instant Call</h1>


<script src="https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/dist/RTCMultiConnection.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
  }
  // Let's check whether notification permissions have already been granted
  //else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {

   // var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
    // If it's okay let's create a notification
  //}
  // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
  else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
    Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
      // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
     // if (permission === "granted") {

     // }
    });
  }
  // At last, if the user has denied notifications, and you 
  // want to be respectful there is no need to bother them any more.

var connection = new RTCMultiConnection();
// this line is VERY_important
connection.socketURL = 'https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com:443/';
// all below lines are optional; however recommended.
connection.session = {
    audio: true,
    video: true,
    data:   true,
    //screen: true,
    //oneway: true
};
connection.sdpConstraints.mandatory = {
    OfferToReceiveAudio: true,
    OfferToReceiveVideo: true
};
connection.onstream = function(event) {
    document.body.appendChild( event.mediaElement );
  //var notification = new Notification("New Call!");
};
var predefinedRoomId = prompt('Please enter room-id', 'xyzxyzxyz');

connection.openOrJoin(predefinedRoomId);

if (connection.newParticipant === true) {
  var notification = new Notification("New Call!");
}
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this return if you remove it work, return is supposed to be used inside of a function:

```
if (window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission() == 0) {
  window.webkitNotifications.createNotification('icon.png', 'Notification Title', 'Notification content...');
} else {
  // Note that we can't call requestPermission from here as we are in the
  // callback function and not triggered just on user action
  console.log('You have to click on "Set notification permissions for this page" ' + 'first to be able to receive notifications.');
  **return;**
}
```

> The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to
>   be returned to the function caller. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Comment: You half-fixed it. It now only shows one end of the connection though, unlike js fiddle which can show two user's webcams

Comment: I'm out for the night no computer, is there an error message? Look for different js code between the fiddle and the other, if not I'll look at it Monday again

Comment: Edited. Everything works except for the *notify about new participants* feature as shown in edited post. Enjoy your weekend.